# Using python zeep to consume web service. How to handle this response?

Tags: python, zeep

I am using a zeep client to consume a web service that is supposed to return me a file in base64binary format. I am using the following code.

```
try:
    client = Client('https://host.com/xmlpserver/services/v2/CatalogService?wsdl')
    response = client.service.downloadObject('/~fin_impl/INVITEM20.xdo','username','password')
    print(response)

except zeepExceptions.Fault as fault:
    print(fault.detail)
```

However, I am not sure what format is this response in and how to decode it.

```
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00o\xb8\x9cP\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00_report.xdo\x8dT\xcbN\xdc0\x14\xdd\xf3\x15V6\xacH\x02tQ\x01\x03*/i\xa4\x99\x01\r\x94v\x87\x8cs\x87\xb1\xf0K\xf65\xc9t\xd1o\xefu^\xa2\x14\xaaI\x94\x85\x8f\x8f}\xcf\xb99\xf6\xc9Y\xa3\x15{\x05\x1f\xa45l\xc2v\xf7\xf3r\x97\x81\x11\xb6\x92\xe69\x01\x11W{_w\xcfNwN<8\xeb\x91\xd1\x02\x13&\xd9\x1a\xd1\x1d\x15E;\xca\xad\xe7BA.\xac.l\xe3\x12\xe8\xb2\x8ex\xd4\x84j$\xd7\xf4\xe4\xf5!\xd1\x9f\x8b\x83\xb2\xdc/~\xcegwb\r\x9ag\x83\x86Iv\x90\x97\x19\xab8\xf2\xb9\xad@M2\xf4\x112\x16\x03\x9cKw\xcb=\xd7\x80D\x1dp\xe7m\x15\x05\xf8\x05\xe1\x93l%\xcd\x1e}\xdc\x08\xc9\xd5\x85\xd5\xda\x1a\xa2\x0c\x8b\x1en:\xd6\x1b\xe8\x9e\x87\x97ke\xeb\x04\x8a\x18\xd0\xeaK\xaa|a\rz\xabZ\x90\x93\xbe[\xf0\xdf\x03\xf8\xa1f\x8b\xddi\xeeq\t+\x0faM\x85\xb9\n\xc3L\xa2\xbe\x9b8\xdda\x8c\x9d\x8c\xa6X\xf4\xb4y\xf1\xfbz\xbax\x9c\xceog\xc5t\xf10\xbd\xbf\x9a\xe7M\xa5\xb3\xa2\'C\x10^:\xa4\x9e\xf4\x08Yu\xe0q\xc3L\xeb"\xacm\xdd\x0b\r\xd4>\xae"\xf4\x02?\xe6[\xa3\xa4\x81\xad\x98\x0e\xccL\x9a\x97\xa9Y@\xfdC\x9a\xca\xd6\xdb,\xe3\x11\xed2\x9a\x91\xdaY\xff\x98\xdb6\xea\xd2\x8a\xa8\xc1\xe06\x9b\'\xb7\xcb6\x80I\xd9V\x86y\xd8\x18\xb1\xf6\xd6\xd8\x18\xb6\xd5\xe5\xbc\xb4^\xe2f$\x1b\xeb5W\xffu\x11=O\x7fi\\rX~F\xef\xfe\x16T\xe7\x9b\xab\x06\xbf9\xf7\x89\xa41\xe4]N)}\xe49m\x9c\xb1\x80\x1b\x95d\x0e\x94\x99\x15m\xf1#\n\xfe\x9a\x94\xff\xa2\x12\\\x1dSa\xedp\x9c\x0c\xb2\x82\xe3a{\x04\xed\x14G\x08\xac\x82\x15\x8f\n\'Y\x1f\xbf\xc7\x83\x92\xde\xfd\xb2\xfc\xd2\x05\xf6-\x9b)\xfe\x94N\xe3\xbf\xd4.\xcco\xf1\x04\xe7MJ%n\x1c\xa9\x85F\x80\xca\x98\x8d\xe8"^\xa7\x86\xe2\x08\xf6\x1a\xde\xa1\x8a\x94\'\x9f@]\xadd\xe0O\n\xe6<\xa4\xf3\xda\xcb\x19\x8e"\x17(_\xc7\xd1\xab\x84\xfa\xa6\x8d\xf9\xdf\xc1(F\xcft\x8d\x15\xdd=v\xba\xf3\x07PK\x07\x08\xe8\xc9\xba\xb2-\x02\x00\x00\xfc\x04\x00\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00o\xb8\x9cP\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00INVITEM_20201004.xls.png\x03\x00PK\x07\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00o\xb8\x9cP\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00INVITEM_20201004_en.xls\xed]\x07\\SI ........'
```

Please suggest, Thanks

Comment: It looks like you've received a [zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) archive.

Comment: Yes it’s a zip file. Is there a way to convert this into base64?

Comment: You can use Python's `base64` module, of course, but why would you want to do that? You would just have to convert it back into binary and unzip it before you could use it. Adding the base64 encode/decode would seem to add an unnecessary step.

Comment: @larsks Thank you!! I spent 4 hours on this. I thought I needed to convert this into base64 to save it on the filesystem.

Comment: @larsks just a quick question, the web service returns the file in base64Binary format, but when I print the response, its already converted to bytes. So maybe the zeep module automatically converts the file into bytes?

Comment: Possibly! I'm not familiar with either the web service or the module you're using so I can't say.